# Is there a way to show Mahapps message dialogs without background overlay?

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I want to show messages in my Mahapps application without graying out the background.

I already tried to find a way with custom themes and custom accents. But no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `OverlayBrush` of the `MetroWindow` to `Transparent`:

```
OverlayBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
await this.ShowMessageAsync("This is the title", "Some message");
```